# I am develop a app use flutter. I use flutter_ble_peripheral and flutter_blue_plus, but not working. AdvertiseData can not be scaned by another phone

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

1、prepare the AdvertiseData

```
AdvertiseData advertiseData = AdvertiseData(serviceUuid: uuid)
```

// the uuid is current user id, eg: ABCDEFFF-eb5c-58f9-29ca-2f2af14b9b78

2、send the data

```
AdvertiseSetParameters advertiseSetParameters = AdvertiseSetParameters();
await FlutterBlePeripheral().start(advertiseData: advertiseData, advertiseSetParameters: advertiseSetParameters);
```

3、start scan

```
FlutterBluePlus flutterBlue = FlutterBluePlus.instance;
var _ = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
      for (ScanResult r in results) {
        for (String uuid in r.advertisementData.serviceUuids) {
          // check scan result
        }
      }
    });
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 6));
```

I run the code on a iphone and a android, but can not scan the other one‘s uuid.

Can anyone help me to find why it not working